# Is hiding and adding the same component in different place good to performance?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

**Scenario:**

I have a **Profile Component** and **Navbar Component**, the Profile Component is not in my Navbar Component, now when the screen gets smaller, the hamburger menu will show and it contains the Navbar Component's links, I want my Profile Component to be along with the Navbar when the screen gets smaller then hide the original Profile Component. So my plan is to copy the Profile Component into Navbar already the toggles it along with the hamburger when the screen gets smaller.

I have a complex layout for my web app (complex for me) that is why I did not put the Profile Component into Navbar Component. The Navbar Component is in the side and the Profile Component is at the top.

Is this approach an okay? Is it good in performance or should I restructure the layout?

This is what I mean in case I didn't explain it clearly.
[image]

Comment: Nesting a component within another component is extremely unlikely to cause any sort of performance issue, and nested components are in fact highly encouraged in the React space. The performance of the Profile component itself is what will matter here, not where on the page it is placed. Also, anything that you don't render is removed from the DOM by React, so they will not impact performance. Of course, if you are rendering the Profile component twice and just hiding one of them with CSS, that certainly can impact performance. Ideally, only render what the user sees on the screen

Comment: Thanks so I think I will go to my plan. Im using React-Bootstrap, and right now what I have on my sleeves is adding the Profile in the navbar and initialize it to display: none, then shows it in mobile view, and vice-versa to my main Profile, initialize it to display block then hides in mobile view.

Comment: You should ideally use the built-in bootstrap classes to do this for you, if you aren't already: [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#responsive-utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#responsive-utilities)

Answer (score -1):

An approach that allow you to display different version of the `Menu` component based on the screen width is a conditionally rendered component.
In order to determine your screen size dynamically in React, I would use the [useMediaQuery hook](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-media-query).

```
function Menu() {
   const isDesktop = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 768px)");
   if (isDesktop) {
       return <DesktopMenu/>
   } else {
       return <MobileMenu/>
   }
}

function MobileMenu() {
   // render the mobile menu here
   return <div>Mobile Menu</div>
}

function DesktopMenu() {
   // render the desktop menu here
   return <div>Desktop Menu</div>
}
```

**Caveat:** If you are using SSR, the output will be `false` regardless of the media-query supplied. Therefore, if you are using SSR (Next.js, etc...) please be mindful of this problem, as it may lead to hydration problem.

Comment: Hmm, I think this didn't answer my question. First time knowing of useMediaQuery. Im using React-Bootstrap (and I cant change it anymore) so I think I will use your approach to my next project instead.

Comment: @Zowy `react-bootstrap` uses [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) under the hood to achieve it's responsive design, so by using `react-bootstrap` you are essentially already using media queries in your CSS